# forkJoin some observables with name observable function in result?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular6, angular2-observables

Lets  suppose there is array of Observable function:

```
A(): Observable<any>
B(): Observable<any>
```

Then using forkJoin I await response from both Observables:

```
let g = forkJoin([A(), B()]);
```

After subscription on `g` I can get results from both Observables.

Due this question, how to know from which Observable I have got result, I mean A(), or B().

Is it possible to get names or reference to these functions?

**More detailed explanation:**

I have unknown number of Observable functions. I need to wait them executions, to get response then enable button. So, also I need to handle response in each of them body, or in common body response in forkJoin

Comment: They'll be in the same order they went in, `([aResult, bResult]) => ...`

Comment: It can be not obvious A and B, it can be different number of Observable function

Comment: You get an array in subscription

Comment: Same applies though, you'll get an array of results in the same order you forkJoined over.

Comment: I can have some Observables in array, unknown number. See my edited question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new observable will resolve an array of results, which are in the same order as that specified in the `forkJoin`

```
g.subscribe([a, b] => {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
})
```

See [Example 5 from the docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

Comment: I have unknown number of `Observable` function. I need to wait them executions, to get response then enable button. So, also I need to handle response in each of them body, or in common body response in `forkJoin`

Comment: Lets simplify my issue, I have some Observable functions and I need handle response in them (subscribe)